# Print specific div's and a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code right now is this:

```
function printPage() {
    var prtContent = document.getElementById("data");
    alert(prtContent.toSource());
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
}
```

Now the div that gets printed is data. In data there is a table but when I try to print this it doesn't show as a table. How can I make this to code to print a table?

My second question is that I have another div called title. Which I also want to print above the table. Really hope someone can help me out.

**BEST ANSWER:**

So the best and easiest way is to create a print css file and link it in your page for example in the header using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Css file example:

```
.class, #divId { display:none; }
```

The easiest way to check if you are applying on to the right div id or class name check the css appliances in your browser and add the css rules there.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't show as a table" -- what does it show?

Comment: Your code works for me and renders a table. Maybe you were expecting it to be styled differently?

Comment: I see what i want it to print. But I don't have borders in my table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a better way to do this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

inside the css hide `display:none' on everything you don't want to print and show
and this works like a charm.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? I have to create a different css page with everything I don't want to show as display:none. The code you pasted. Should I put this behind the button or in my javascript?

Comment: no javascript needed. Create a new css file and link it with in your page and then when you print it gets loading automatically.. here are the steps http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html

Comment: I haven't read the entire file yet but if i'm right I can also use this to style the print page? I'm so excited to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, you'll just need to add a couple lines.

```
function printPage() {
    var prtContent = document.getElementById("data");
    alert(prtContent.toSource());
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');

    //Add these two lines 
    var titleDiv = document.getElementById("title");    
    WinPrint.document.write(titleDiv.outerHTML);

    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
}
```